# Python / Pandas Reading Data with pandas-datareader from Yahoo Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

> FutureWarning: pandas.util.testing is deprecated. Use the functions in
>   the public API at pandas.testing instead.

My packages are up-to-date currently but still get the same error above. It'd be great to hear any advice how am I gonna solve the issue.

Comment: Please share the entire error message, and the version of each library you're using.

Answer (score 1):

That was depreciated a couple years ago.  Please try it this way.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import datetime
from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation
from sklearn import metrics
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
from sklearn import cluster, covariance, manifold


start = '2019-02-01'
end = '2020-02-01'

tickers = ['MMM',
'ABT',
'ABBV',
'ABMD',
'ACN',
'ATVI']

thelen = len(tickers)

price_data = []
for ticker in tickers:
    prices = wb.DataReader(ticker, start = start, end = end, data_source='yahoo')[['Open','Adj Close']]
    price_data.append(prices.assign(ticker=ticker)[['ticker', 'Open', 'Adj Close']])

#names = np.reshape(price_data, (len(price_data), 1))

names = pd.concat(price_data)
names.reset_index()
```